# Accessing array element at constant index in a batch-file

Tags: arrays, batch-file

> I've mentioned constant index in the title because all question in StackOverflow related to array indexing in a batch file were focused on accessing array using variable index inside a loop.

I'm new to batch scripting. I want to print array value with a constant index if the array is initialized as a list(in one line) rather than each element being initialized individually. I've written a snippet in which I can print the value of `arr` but not `list`.

```
@echo off
set arr[0]=1
set arr[1]=2
set arr[2]=3
set list=1 2 3 4
REM Result is 2
echo %arr[1]%
REM Won't print
echo %list[1]%
```

Comment: Did you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51191502/6738015), just down the page a little?

Comment: if you're new then probably just save yourself sometime by using powershell

Answer (score 0):

A list in a string isn't an array, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51194867/6811411) 2 days ago shows how to turn a string list into an array.

To have the array index zero based use this changed version

```
:: SO_51225079.cmd
@echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set arr[0]=1
set arr[1]=2
set arr[2]=3
set i=-1&set "list= 1 2 3 4"
Set "list=%list: ="&Set /a i+=1&Set "list[!i!]=%"
set list

REM Result is 2
echo %arr[1]%
REM Won't print
echo %list[1]%
```

Sample output:

```
> SO_51225079.cmd
list[0]=1
list[1]=2
list[2]=3
list[3]=4
2
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be confusing Batch and PowerShell.  In PowerShell, yes, you can initialize an array on one line:

```js
$list = 1, 2, 3, 4
$list[1]
# output here would be 2
```

In the Batch scripting language, there are no array objects.  You can simulate arrays by having similarly or sequentially named scalar variables, but the Batch language doesn't provide methods such as `split()` or `splice()` or `push()` or similar.

Often in Batch, splitting a string on spaces (or commas or semicolons) is accomplished by tokenizing using a `for` loop.

```js
@echo off & setlocal

rem // Quoting "varname=val" is the safest way to set a scalar variable
set "list=1 2 3 4"

rem // When performing arithmetic using "set /a", spacing is more flexible.
set /a ubound = -1

rem // Split %list% by tokenizing using a for loop
for %%I in (%list%) do (
    set /a ubound += 1

    rem // Use "call set... %%ubound%%" to avoid evaluating %ubound% prematurely.
    rem // Otherwise, %ubound% is expanded when the for loop is reached and keeps the
    rem // same value on every loop iteration.
    call set "arr[%%ubound%%]=%%~I"
)

rem // output results
set arr[

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem // You can also loop from 0..%ubound% using for /L
for /L %%I in (0, 1, %ubound%) do echo Element %%I: !arr[%%I]!
endlocal
```

As a side note, in that code block I demonstrated two methods of delaying expansion of variables in Batch -- using `call set` and `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` using exclamation marks where delayed retrieval is desired.  There are times when it's useful to know both.  The `enabledelayedexpansion` method is usually more readable / more easily maintained, but in some circumstances can clobber values where exclamation marks possibly exist (such as file names).  For that reason, I try to avoid enabling delayed expansion for the entire script.

---

[LotPings' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51225547/1683264) is clever, but limited in application.  The way it works is, using [substring substitution](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) it sets and evaluates the value of `list` to a string of commands (separated by &).  Unfortunately, it destroys the value of `%list%` in the process, and it cannot handle values containing spaces or exclamation marks.

```js
@echo off & setlocal

set "list="The quick brown" "fox jumps over" "the lazy dog!!!""
set /a ubound = -1

for %%I in (%list%) do (
    set /a ubound += 1
    call set "arr[%%ubound%%]=%%~I"
)

rem // output results
set arr[
```

The `for` method of splitting will correctly maintain quoted spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Batch has only one type of variable: string.

An array and a list are very different things (and it is discussed, if those even exist in batch, but they can be emulated). In batch, a list isn't different elements, but just a single string, and an array isn't a single structure, but different independend variables.

Nevertheless, you can split a string (that looks like a list) by delimiters (space is a default delimter) with a `for` loop:

```
set list=a b c d
set element=2
for /f "tokens=%element%" %%a in ("%list%") do echo %%a
```

(Note: this is batch syntax. For use directly on command line, replace each `%%a` with `%a`)